# DynamoDB - How to query a nested attribute boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I am following the DynamoDB python tutorial. This step shows how to query the table based on a specific key: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html.

Here is the code for this query:

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3
import json
import decimal
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

# Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url="http://localhost:8000")

table = dynamodb.Table('Movies')

print("Movies from 1992 - titles A-L, with genres and lead actor")

response = table.query(
    ProjectionExpression="#yr, title, info.genres, info.actors[0]",
    ExpressionAttributeNames={ "#yr": "year" }, # Expression Attribute Names for Projection Expression only.
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('year').eq(1992) & Key('title').between('A', 'L')
)

for i in response[u'Items']:
    print(json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder))
```

An example response item is

```
{
    "title": "Juice",
    "year": "1992",
    "info": {
        "actors": [
            "Omar Epps"
        ],
        "genres": [
            "Crime",
            "Drama",
            "Thriller"
        ]
    }
}
```

The table has the two key attributes 'title' and 'year' as well as the nested attribute 'info'. What I am trying to do is query the database and filter the movies by genre, for example get all Drama movies. I am not sure how to do this since the genre key is nested inside info.

I tried to get all the Drama movies from 1992 like this but it came up blank.

```
response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('year').eq(1992),
    FilterExpression=Attr('info.genres').eq('Drama')
)
```

How do I properly filter this query with the nested info attribute?

Comment: DynamoDB is designed to be queried by the keys, so to accomplish what you want you will have to query the entire table and look at the entries one by one after you've gotten them. If you know you will be doing lots of queries like this over and over again I suggest re-thinking either your use of DynamoDB or which keys you want to use.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip

Comment: Since DynamoDb is ill suited for this, do you have a suggestion for a different type of data base to use? I am new to databases

Comment: Maybe MongoDB might be good for your use case.

Comment: hey, how to compare if my 'geners' is an array of objects and I want to compare an attribute of array object . e.g. "genres": [ {"name" : "Crime", description:" "}, {"name" : "Drama",description:" "}, {"name" : "Thriller,"description: " "}, ] I want to compare the name in this example..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `contains` to filter the data from **List** data type.

**genres** -attribute stored as List inside `info` attribute which is a Map data type

```
FilterExpression=Attr('info.genres').contains('Drama')
```

Comment: hey, how to compare  if my 'geners' is an array of objects and I want to compare an attribute of array object . e.g.  "genres": [
            {"name" : "Crime", description:" "},
            {"name" : "Drama",description:" "},
            {"name" : "Thriller,"description: " "},
        ]                       I want to compare the name in this example..

Comment: You still need to create KeyCondition, and what if you want to just use attribute not a Key at all? (all dramas, no matter which year)

Answer (score 2):

Unlike in the accepted answer, to be able to filter all the items with the attribute, you need to use `scan()` instead of `query()`. `query()` requires `KeyCondition` which is unnecessary in your case and forces you to create condition containing f.e. year.

Therefore

```
table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('info.genres').contains('Drama'))
```

should do the job